# Cannot subscript a value of type NSInteger

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have the following code.

```
var caseRate = [NSInteger]()

    // Configure the cell...
    casecell.casename.text = caseName[indexPath.row]
    casecell.casecontent.text = caseDetail[indexPath.row]
    casecell.caserate.text = caseRate [indexPath.row]
```

This line displays an error:

```
    casecell.caserate.text = caseRate? [indexPath.row]
```

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSNumber' to expected argument type 'NSInteger' (aka 'Int')

I've tried different solutions found in other questions, such as using guard, with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to use NSIntegers instead of a Swift type Int, you can do NSNumber.integerValue to get an NSInteger.

Edit:
This question is way more simplistic than I thought. Literally just use string interpolation. 
`casecell.caserate.text = "\(caseRate[indexPath.row])"`

Answer (score 2):

You could Swift-ify your code to something like:

```
struct Case {
    let name: String
    let detail: String
    let rate: Int
}

let cases = [Case]()

// Configure the cell...
let case = cases[indexPath.row]
casecell.casename?.text = case.name
casecell.casecontent?.text = case.detail
casecell.caserate?.text = String(case.rate)
```

This spares you from having to maintain three separate arrays of case information, as well any exception resulting from an inconsistent array `count`.